# TypeScript: Factory pattern to use dynamic imports is not allowing to construct new instance of the object for composition

Tags: javascript, webpack, factory-pattern, ts-loader, dynamic-import

I am implementing factory pattern in Typescript with dynamic imports so that I can initialize the load, initialize (with necessary composition) of the demanded module on run-time.

I am able to load the module dynamically on demand as https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html

However it is not allowing me to initialize the loaded module.
Though in developer console I can do the initialization and even compose it seamlessly by initializing its sub-modules and classes composed in the module.

Struggling a lot to find this solution and tried out many things but didn't get it solved. In C# we can do it using reflection and create instance of libraries and classes as lazy loading without getting direct reference to them.

The error I am getting is "// Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)" when I am doing

```
let y: Interfaces.IComponent =  new comp();
```

to construct it and assign it to varebale with type of interface of the that object is implementing.

same for the parent class type that component is extending

```
let x: ComponentImpl =  new comp();
```

Please have a look at the code of typescript below.

```
    import { Interfaces } from 'shared';
    import { ComponentImpl } from 'core';

    export default class Factory {
        private _loadedModules: Map<string, Interfaces.IComponent> = new Map<string, Interfaces.IComponent>();
        private static _instace: Factory;

        private constructor() {

        }

        public static get Instance(): Factory {
            return this._instace || (this._instace = new this());
        }

        public getComponent(component: string): Promise<Interfaces.IComponent> {
            return new Promise<Interfaces.IComponent>(async (resolve, reject) => {
                let comp = this._loadedModules.get(component);
                if (comp !== null) {
                    comp = await import(`./${component}`);
                    if (comp) {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        // ** NOTE: On run time I can see the module is loaded corrctly and I can initialze its sub classes in developer console.
                        // like controller = new comp.controller(); (get console log from constructor)
                        // controller.sayHello();
                        // controller.setAPIInstance(new comp.getAPI());
                        // controller.saveToAPI();
                        let y: Interfaces.IComponent =  new comp(); // Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)
                        let x: ComponentImpl =  new comp(); // Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)
                        this._loadedModules.set(component, comp);


                        resolve(comp);
                    } else {
                        reject("Unable lo load module");
                    }
                } else {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve(comp);
                    }, 1);
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Ishaan, Did you get the solution for this?. Facing the same problem. Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following solution which worked in my case:

```
let x: ComponentImpl =  new (comp as typeof ComponentImpl )()
```

See also this ticket from TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2081